# How to get second highest value from a column pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by

I have a PySpark DataFrame and I would like to get the second highest value of `ORDERED_TIME` (DateTime Field `yyyy-mm-dd` format) after a groupBy applied to 2 columns, namely `CUSTOMER_ID` and `ADDRESS_ID`.

A customer can have many orders associated with an address and I would like to get the second most recent order for a `(customer,address)` pair

My approach was to make a window and partition according to `CUSTOMER_ID` and `ADDRESS_ID`, sort by `ORDERED_TIME`

```
sorted_order_times = Window.partitionBy("CUSTOMER_ID", "ADDRESS_ID").orderBy(col('ORDERED_TIME').desc())

df2 = df2.withColumn("second_recent_order", (df2.select("ORDERED_TIME").collect()[1]).over(sorted_order_times))
```

However, I get an error saying `ValueError: 'over' is not in list`

Could anyone suggest the right way to go about solving this problem?

Please let me know if any other information is needed

Sample Data

```
+-----------+----------+-------------------+
|USER_ID    |ADDRESS_ID|       ORDER DATE  | 
+-----------+----------+-------------------+
|        100| 1000     |2021-01-02         |
|        100| 1000     |2021-01-14         |
|        100| 1000     |2021-01-03         |
|        100| 1000     |2021-01-04         |
|        101| 2000     |2020-05-07         |
|        101| 2000     |2021-04-14         |
+-----------+----------+-------------------+
```

Expected Output

```
+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|USER_ID    |ADDRESS_ID|       ORDER DATE  |second_recent_order
+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|        100| 1000     |2021-01-02          |2021-01-04 
|        100| 1000     |2021-01-14          |2021-01-04 
|        100| 1000     |2021-01-03          |2021-01-04 
|        100| 1000     |2021-01-04          |2021-01-04 
|        101| 2000     |2020-05-07          |2020-05-07 
|        101| 2000     |2021-04-14          |2020-05-07 
+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data along with the expected output?

Comment: Sorry for missing out on that, I've edited the question with sample input and output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another way to do it. Using `collect_list`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window


sorted_order_times = Window.partitionBy("CUSTOMER_ID", "ADDRESS_ID").orderBy(F.col('ORDERED_TIME').desc()).rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,  Window.unboundedFollowing)
df2 = (
  df
  .withColumn("second_recent_order", (F.collect_list(F.col("ORDERED_TIME")).over(sorted_order_times))[1])
)
df2.show()
```

[image: Final output]

Answer (score 1):

You can use window here in the following way, but you will get null if only one row would be in a group

```py
sorted_order_times = Window.partitionBy("CUSTOMER_ID", "ADDRESS_ID").orderBy(desc('ORDERED_TIME')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df2 = df2.withColumn(
    "second_recent_order",
    collect_list("ORDERED_TIME").over(sorted_order_times).getItem(1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a lookup table with the second most recent orders for all couples of `CUSTOMER_ID` and `ADDRESS_ID`, and then join it with the original dataframe.
I assume that your `ORDERED_TIME` column is already a *timestamp* type.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# define window
w = Window().partitionBy('CUSTOMER_ID', 'ADDRESS_ID').orderBy(F.desc('ORDERED_TIME'))

# create lookup table
second_highest = df \
  .withColumn('rank', F.dense_rank().over(w)) \
  .filter(F.col('rank') == 2) \
  .select('CUSTOMER_ID', 'ADDRESS_ID', 'ORDERED_TIME')

# join with original dataframe
df = df.join(second_highest, on=['CUSTOMER_ID', 'ADDRESS_ID'], how='left')

df.show()

+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|CUSTOMER_ID|ADDRESS_ID|       ORDERED_TIME|       ORDERED_TIME|
+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|        100| 158932441|2021-01-02 13:35:57|2021-01-04 09:36:10|
|        100| 158932441|2021-01-14 19:14:08|2021-01-04 09:36:10|
|        100| 158932441|2021-01-03 13:33:52|2021-01-04 09:36:10|
|        100| 158932441|2021-01-04 09:36:10|2021-01-04 09:36:10|
|        101| 281838494|2020-05-07 13:35:57|2020-05-07 13:35:57|
|        101| 281838494|2021-04-14 19:14:08|2020-05-07 13:35:57|
+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

*Note: in your expected output you wrote `2021-04-14 19:14:08` for `CUSTOMER_ID == 101`, but it's actually `2020-05-07 13:35:57` because it's in year 2020.*

Answer (score 0):

Two windows can be used: sorted for get rows in proper order, and unsorted combined with "first" function, for get second row (Scala):

```
val df2 = Seq(
  (100, 158932441, "2021-01-02 13:35:57"),
  (100, 158932441, "2021-01-14 19:14:08"),
  (100, 158932441, "2021-01-03 13:33:52"),
  (100, 158932441, "2021-01-04 09:36:10"),
  (101, 281838494, "2020-05-07 13:35:57"),
  (101, 281838494, "2021-04-14 19:14:08")
).toDF("CUSTOMER_ID", "ADDRESS_ID", "ORDERED_TIME")

val sorted_order_times = Window
  .partitionBy("CUSTOMER_ID", "ADDRESS_ID")
  .orderBy(desc("ORDERED_TIME"))

val unsorted_order_times = Window
  .partitionBy("CUSTOMER_ID", "ADDRESS_ID")

df2
  .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(sorted_order_times))
  .withColumn("second_recent_order",
  first(
    when($"row_number" === lit(2), $"ORDERED_TIME").otherwise(null), true
  ).over(unsorted_order_times))
  .drop("row_number")
```

Output:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|CUSTOMER_ID|ADDRESS_ID|ORDERED_TIME       |second_recent_order|
+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|100        |158932441 |2021-01-14 19:14:08|2021-01-04 09:36:10|
|100        |158932441 |2021-01-04 09:36:10|2021-01-04 09:36:10|
|100        |158932441 |2021-01-03 13:33:52|2021-01-04 09:36:10|
|100        |158932441 |2021-01-02 13:35:57|2021-01-04 09:36:10|
|101        |281838494 |2021-04-14 19:14:08|2020-05-07 13:35:57|
|101        |281838494 |2020-05-07 13:35:57|2020-05-07 13:35:57|
+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```